# How to mark branch as stable using Composer?

Tags: php, git, composer-php

In a Git repository of a project i have made a branch from master starting in a `1.0` tagged commit, and i called this branch `1.0.x-dev`

I want to use this branch for patching.

The problem arises when i require the latest patch in another project using:

`composer require foo/bar:^1.0`

It retrieves the original `1.0` tagged commit, not the latest commit of `1.0.x-dev` branch.

I see that this happens because i have setted `"prefer-stable": true` (otherwise it works)

Then, There is any way to specify to composer that this branch is stable avoiding tagging every patch?

Comment: how is the composer file populated in the `1.0.x-dev` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `composer require foo/bar:"1.0.x-dev as 1.0.0"` in your project - Composer will use `1.0` branch and treat it as `1.0.0` release. For Composer only tagged releases are considered as stable.